# How can I edit my code on CPLEX about tuple?

Tags: tuples, cplex

Good evening! I have created this tuple in which I go to identify with 1 the jobs that can be carried out at night and 0 those during the day. in the set D I would like to select only the jobs that can be carried out at night, therefore those with nightyes equal to 1. So in my example I want D to be equal to (1,4,5). I try in this way but CPLEX returns all the jobs indiscriminately. How can I change this code? Thank you.

tuple night {

int jobs;
int nightyes;

}

{night} jobsnotturni =...;

{int} nightyes = {i.nightyes|i in jobsnotturni };

{int} D = {i.jobs|i in jobsnotturni, n in nightyes : n==1};

jobsnotturni = {<1,1>, <2,0>,<3,0>,<4,1>,<5,1>};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change your .mod into

```
tuple night {

int jobs; int nightyes;

}

{night} jobsnotturni =...;

{int} nightyes = {i.nightyes|i in jobsnotturni };

{int} D = {i.jobs|i in jobsnotturni: i.nightyes==1};

execute
{
  writeln(D);
}
```

then you ll get

```
{1 4 5}
```

Comment: It works!Thank you!

Comment: Great. Then do not hesitate to accept the answer and maybe vote!

Comment: How can I vote?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers